# if less than 0(negative) days , appear EXPIRED

Tags: php, mysql

Things that i want to achieved: if less than 0(negative) days , appear EXPIRED

What should i do if i wanted to show less than 0(negative) it will show expired instead of showing -1 ?

http://prntscr.com/mip2tc , < this is the output

i know that stackoverflow is not a answer platform , but i have no idea what should i do next to get the result that I want(don't know where to start)

below is my code what should i add afterwards?

```
$dbDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // Database date
    $endDate =  strtotime("".$result['duedate']."");    // current time
    $diff = $endDate - $dbDate; /// diffrence
     $days = intval(intval($diff) / (3600*24));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this `$days = intval(intval($diff) / (3600*24));`

to this:

```
$days = intval(intval($diff) / (3600*24));
$newDays = $days < 0 ? 'EXPIRED' : $days;
```

and print value of $newDays.

Comment: thanks , i got what i wanted now . thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could manage the resulting aspect  eg:

```
   $days = intval(intval($diff) / (3600*24));

   ..
```

where you show the result you could use a  conditioned echo

```
  echo   $days < 0 ? 'EXPIRED' :  $days ;
```